# How to create a special log for my ntpdate?

Tags: log

```
ntpdate  -s 0.asia.pool.ntp.org
```

s:Divert logging output from the standard output (default) to  the          system  syslog  facility.

```
tail  /var/log/syslog
```

The ntpdate log will be seen.

I want to create a special log file in /var/log/ntpdate.log for ntpdate command to write into it,how to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running it like this:

`ntpdate 0.asia.pool.ntp.org >> /var/log/ntpdate.log`

This way you redirect and append the standard output of ntpdate to the file.